# Is it possible to download or update WhatsApp Desktop App Beta version?

Tags: windows-10, whatsapp

The reason why I'm interested in the Beta version is because recently WhatsApp allowed to make video calls from its Desktop App. The only problem is that it is not widely available and it is just testing on a select few.

[Image showing the Video Call option in the Beta version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVhoP.png)